# bind data to combobox in datagrid in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, datagridview, combobox, silverlight-5.0

how can i bind the data  returning from WCF in combox in grid . the combobox is not in edit mode. I am able to display the static data but not the data returning from WCF.

Answer (score 2):

u can use *RelativeSource* to search needed DataContext/ViewModel/Page/UserControl in the elements tree
example for the ViewModel where DataGrid itemssource defined near ComBoxCollectionSource:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=sdk:DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.ComboBoxColloctionSource} />
```

Comment: i have this public Dictionary<string, int> test() { Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>(); dictionary.Add("Cat", 2); dictionary.Add("Dog", 1); dictionary.Add("llama", 0); dictionary.Add("iguana", -1); return dictionary; } in wcf side. so i will getdictionary in client with e.result. after that how can i bind? sorry, I have jsut started learning silverlight

Comment: @Dmitry: To above answer i have one query How can i set SelectedValue for this combobox i tried using    SelectedValue="{Binding     DataContext.SelectedPriorMonthsCoverage,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource=    {RelativeSource AncestorType=sdk:DataGrid} `  . But this doesnt work :-(

Comment: I guess SelectedValue should be part of ur collections, i.e. as a property in item of that collection. And would lead to more discussion over comments instead u should ask ur question n with more detail on the syntax n data type in context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the static data is the stuff you enter into the Items property by hand. The syntax for a combobox is a bit different, but here it is:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=<your collection>,Mode=OneTime}" SelectedValuePath="<id-field>" DisplayMemberPath="<display-field>" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=<your-property>,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The parameters ending in PATH above just have the names of the properties as a string.

**EDIT**: If you're using a dictionary, you would use:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=<your dictionsry>,Mode=OneTime}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=<your-int-property>,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: i have this public Dictionary<string, int> test() { Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>(); dictionary.Add("Cat", 2); dictionary.Add("Dog", 1); dictionary.Add("llama", 0); dictionary.Add("iguana", -1); return dictionary; } in wcf side. so i will getdictionary in client with e.result. after that how can i bind? sorry, I have jsut started learning silverlight